# Assigning Unique ID's to each instance of a class

Tags: c++, xml, algorithm

I am importing items from an XML file. Each XML element (`FoodItem`, `Person`, `Order`, `CoffeeRun`) is a class & each of these elements will have a unique ID(unique to that class).

```
<person>
<id>0</id>
<name>...</name>
</person>

<FoodItem>
<id>0</id>
<name>Coffee</name>
</FoodItem>
```

I am trying to develop a sub class `DatabaseItem`, that ensures that no 2 objects of a class have the same ID. Can you assist me, by helping me develop an efficient algorithm that makes sure no object will have the same ID as another?

My 2 approaches seem a little inefficient to me:

- Use a static class vector that contains all the USED ids so far. When a new `DatabaseID( int requestedID )` object is created I check whether the ID is available by going over all the used values in the vector to check the ID is not already there, I think thats Big-O'n speed?
- Use a static class bool `vector` where each element of the `vector` corresponds to an id (so `vector[1]` will correspond to the object with ID 1). I check if an ID is already taken by seeing if that element in the `vector` is true `if ( v[nID] == true ) { // this ID is already taken }`. This seems inefficient because it means my `vector` will take a lot of memeory right?
- I am not familiar with using maps in C++ but maybe I should use one here?

Any advice on an efficient algorithm would be really helpful:

```
class DatabaseItem
{
    public:
        static unsigned int instanceCount;

        DatabaseItem()
        {
            // Assign next available ID
        }

        DatabaseItem( unsigned int nID )
        {
            // Check that that id is not already taken
            // if id is taken, look for next available id &
            // give the item that id
        }

    private:
        unsigned int uniqueID;
};

// My solution: Do you have any better ideas that ensure no objects jave the same ID?
// This seems REALLY inefficient...
class DatabaseItem
{
    public:
        static unsigned int instanceCount;
        static vector <unsigned int> usedIDs;

        DatabaseItem()
        {
            DatabaseItem::instanceCount++;
            uniqueID = instanceCount;
            usedIDs.add( instanceCount );
        }

        DatabaseItem( unsigned int nID )
        {
            if ( isIDFree( nID ) )
            {
                uniqueID = nID;
            }
            else uniqueID = nextAvailableID();

            DatabaseItem::instanceCount++;
        }

        bool isIDFree( unsigned int nID )
        {
            // This is pretty slow to check EVERY element

            for (int i=0; i<usedIDs.size(); i++)
            {
                if (usedIDs[i] == nID)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }

        unsigned int nextAvailableID()
        {
            while ( true )
            {
                unsigned int ID = 0;

                if ( isIDFree( ID ) )
                {
                    return ID;
                }
                else ID++;
            }
        }

    private:
        unsigned int uniqueID;
};


// Alternate that uses boolean vector to track which ids are occupied
// This means I take 30000 boolean memory when I may not need all that
class DatabaseItem
{
    public:
        static unsigned int instanceCount;
        static const unsigned int MAX_INSTANCES = 30000;
        static vector <bool> idVector;

        // Is this how I initialise a static class vector...? (note this code will be outside the class definition)
        // vector <bool> DatabaseItem::idVector( MAX_INSTANCES, false );

        DatabaseItem()
        {
            uniqueID           = nextAvailableID();
            idVector[uniqueID] = true;
        }

        DatabaseItem( unsigned int nID )
        {
            if ( nID >= MAX_INSTANCES )
            {
                // not sure how I shd handle this case?
            }

            if ( idVector[nID] == false )
            {
                uniqueID      = nID;
                idVector[nID] = true;
            }
            else
            {
                uniqueID           = nextAvailableID();
                idVector[uniqueID] = true;
            }

            instanceCount++;
        }

        unsigned int nextAvailableID()
        {
            for (int i=0; i<idVector.size(); i++)
            {
                if ( !idVector[i] )
                {
                    return i;
                }
            }

            return -1;
        }

        bool isIDFree( unsigned int nID )
        {
            // Note I cannot do this: Because I am using Mosync API & it doesn't support any C++ exceptions'

            // I declare idVector with no size! so not idVector( 30000, false)... just idVector;
            // then I allow an exception to occur to check if an id is taken

            try
            {
                return idVector[nID];
            }
            catch (...)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

    private:
        unsigned int uniqueID;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

A `vector<bool>` is implemented with one bit per bool, so it's not wasting as much space as you assume.

A `set<unsigned int>` is the easy solution to this. A `vector<bool>` is faster. Both could use a bit of memory. Depending on your usage patterns, there's a few other solutions:

- An `unsigned int all_taken_upto_this;` combined with a `set<int>` covering all the oddball ID's that are higher than `all_taken_upto_this` - remove from set and increase the counter when you can.
- A `map<unsigned int, unsigned int>` which is logically treated as `begin,end` of either taken or free sequences. This'll take a little fiddling to implement correctly (merging consecutive map elements when you add the last ID in between two elements e.g.)

You could probably use a premade "sparse bitset" type data structure - I don't know any implementations OTOH.

Comment: .. um isnt a bool variable in c++ one byte not bit? Are you thinking of std::bitset?

Comment: @Mack: No I'm thinking of the horrid abomination of a standard-specified specialization of `vector<bool>` which breaks a bunch of semantics without providing anything we can't get from better alternatives like bitset. (And yes, this is a pet peeve - I really really don't like `vector<bool>`)

Comment: @Mack, while it has been regretted by the same people that added it, `std::vector<bool>` is not an `std::vector` containing `bool` objects, but rather an specialization where each element takes exactly one bit of memory. The regrets come from the fact that you cannot provide direct access to the elements as with the rest of the vectors, so it behaves differently even if it looks the same (this is solved by returning proxy objects that modify the appropriate bit in the original vector, as you cannot have a pointer/reference to a bit)

Comment: @David: As a side note, after reading your comment I suddenly realized that I've incorrectly been writing "a std::" instead of "an std::" for many years... Thanks :P

Comment: Beware: I am not a native speaker, it might be either way and I would not know it. Up until a couple of days ago I was convinced that template arguments could be *deductible*, but then the TAX office kept turning my claims down. I guess they are only *deducible*

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the number of elements and a couple other issues, you might consider actually storing them (or at least pointers to them) in a map. That would be rather simple to implement, but will take some space. On the other hand, it will provide you with fast lookup by `id` which might be a clear advantage if there are cross references in the XML. The map (assuming pointers) would look like:

```
std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<Object> > id_map;
std::shared_ptr<Object> p( new Object( xml ) );
if ( !id_map.insert( std::make_pair( p->id, p ) ).second ) {
   // failed to insert, the element is a duplicate!!!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not locked into using an integer you may look into GUIDs (Global Unique IDs).  Depending on which platform you are using you can generally find a couple of utility functions to dynamically generate a GUID.  If using Visual Studio, I've used the [CoCreateGuid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms688568%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

If you are locked into a 32-bit integer another option option is a hash table.  If each XML element is unique, then a hashing function could generate a unique hash value.  Depending on the size of your data set there is still a small probability of collision.  The one I've used that seems to have a pretty low collision rate with the data set that I've worked with is called the [Jenkins hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins_hash_function)